# how to reset ~/.profile to default

Tags: .profile

I have been playing around with the `~/.profile` file trying to add something permanently to my `$PATH` variable and it seems i have done some damage.

I can't log into ubuntu now. When I enter my password the screen goes black for 1 second and then it goes back to the login screen. If I press Ctrl+Alt+F3 I can log in with the command line. My question is how can I edit `~/.profile` from the command line so I can log in again ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can edit the file using

```
nano ~/.profile
```

To get the default `~/.profile` back use

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

As this will overwrite your modified version you may want to save your version first:

```
cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.invalid
```

Comment: saw that /etc/skel have most of the templates that you should have for solve configuration lost

Answer (score 1):

In case you get an error saying:

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile: command not found
```

try:

```
/usr/bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

If that doesn't work, try with sudo privileges using:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

Then reboot